# Scale part of image or table in CHM

Tags: html, css, image, tabular, chm

I want to put the company header on the front page of our CHM manuals. Because users are able to scale the CHM, the header should scale with the width of the manual. The height should not scale.
The problem is that both the left and right side of the header must remain intact, so only the center of the header should scale. The left side has a cut-off corner of which the angle must not change. The right side contains an image.

Image:

[image]

Is it possible to do this with CSS or HTML, with either an image or a table?

**EDIT:**

I still have 2 issues with it that I cannot fix. Hopefully you can help a bit more. The background color on the header_center also gives a small underline after compiled into a CHM file. It have made it red for visability. Also when I scale the CHM window, white space appears between header_left and header_center and I have no idea why. This is solved if I give all 3 headers a background color, but I do not want a line under header_right because of the image. Any ideas?

These images are the result at this stage:

[image: Header not scaled]
[image: Header scaled]

Answer (score 0):

You know, CHM is like a ZIP format and may contain HTML as well as CSS. Below I have shown one of the possibilities using images. Try it and change for your needs (see HTML below). The background colors in `<colgroup>` are only used for demonstration purposes. If there is text in the middle, the corresponding color from the company banner has to be set as background color.

[image]

The images I used:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Make sure an external CSS file e.g. design.css is inside you project level structure and added to the [FILES] section of your HHP project file. You can open this *.hhp file with e.g. Notepad++ to add files.
If the files are listed in the [FILES] section the compiler includes them to the CHM file.

```
[FILES] 
welcome.htm 
design.css
How_to_extend\extend_menu.htm 
How_to_extend\power_function.htm 
images\gui_screenshot.jpg
```

**HTML and CSS:**

```
   <html>
     <head>
       <meta name="generator"
       content="HTML Tidy for HTML5 (experimental)" />
       <title></title>
       <style>

   .header {
     width: 100%;
     border-collapse: collapse;
     /*border: 1px solid black;*/
   }

   .header_left{
    width: 81px;
   }

   .header_center{
    /*background-image: url("help-info-de-right-part.png");*/
    /*background-color: #ff33cc;*/
    background-color: #e0e0e0;
    text-align: center;
   }

   .header_right{
    width: 82px;
   }

   .header td {
    padding: 0;
   }

   </style>
   </head>

     <body>
       <table class="header">
         <colgroup>
           <col style="background-color:green;" />
           <col style="background-color:red;" />
           <col style="background-color:yellow;" />
         </colgroup>
         <tr>
           <td class="header_left">
             <img src="help-info-de-left-part.png" />
           </td>
           <td class="header_center">
             <img src="help-info-de-center-part.png" />
           </td>
           <td class="header_right">
             <img src="help-info-de-right-part.png" />
           </td>
         </tr>
       </table>
       <h1>Heading 1</h1>
       <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna
       aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea
       takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
     </body>

   </html>
```

Comment: Apologies for the late reply, it took me a while to get this incorporated and I still have 2 issues with it that I cannot fix. Hopefully you can help a bit more.
The background color on the header_center also gives a small underline. It have made it red for visability.
Also when I scale the CHM window, white space appears between header_left and header_center and I have no idea why. This is solved if I give all 3 headers a background color, but I do not want a line under header_right because of the image. Any ideas?

Comment: I'll have a look to this at home later.

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate it. I have added the images to the original question.

Comment: The problem you described in the question EDIT above is surprising. I had tested the single HTML file in several browsers (Chrome, FireFox, Microsoft Edge, Microsoft Internet Explorer). In a Compiled Help Module (CHM) I now see your problem too. I included the following meta tag without success in the <head> section `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE11"/>`. I currently don't know what the cause is.